# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2308: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, pycharm

```
class Data_Manager():     
    def file_opener(self):
        self.file = askopenfile(mode='r',filetypes=[("Excel Files", "*.xls"),("Excel Files", "*.xlsx"), 
        ("CSV Files", "*. csv")])

       self.data = read_excel(self.file, 'w', newline='', encoding="cp437", errors='ignore')

        print(self.data) x = Data_Manager() x.file_opener()
```

Always when I'm trying to `read_execl` by pandas I got this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position
2308: character maps to <undefined>
```

When I'm doing it with `read_csv` (for csv files) there is no problem and data is received by pycharm. I was searching on the internet and also here but nothing has helped.

Comment: try `encoding="utf8"`

Comment: You have hardcoded `encoding="cp437"` which means if the file *actually* contains some other encoding, there will be trouble. You need to figure out what it really contains.

Answer (score 0):

Function **askopenfile** is sending meany of informations inside **(path, unicode, ...)** not as i thought before only (path). So when i used askopenfile + pandas.read_excel (without any specification), read_excel recived also unicode thats why this error becomes.

So the ***solution*** is to use specific atribute   **.name** then  (read_excel) gets only clear path.

```
file = askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes=[("Excel Files", "*.xls"))
    
data = read_excel(file.name)
```